# error 500.19 on web application

Tags: asp.net, iis

I keep getting the error below,

I Have changed the permissions to give the IIS users full rights to all folders in inetpub, i have made changes to iis and re-installed visual studios, still getting this error any ideas why this would be the case. i copied and pasted the code from my colleague computer and domne the same settings as him and i get errror 500.19 and on his machine it runs fine,

when i try and drbug the code it come up aith an error message with saya can not debug use debug.start without debug, and it still gives me the error.

```
    HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
    The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x8007000d
Config Error    
Config File \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cisiweb2\web.config
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/cisiweb
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cisiweb2
Logon Method    Not yet determined
Logon User  Not yet determined
```

Comment: Well - it seems your web.config has become either invalid or corrupt - possible because of settings you've changed in the IIS. It's not possible for us to see which settings. You'll need to verify your web.config (reroll to working? ) and/or your IIS settings (and application pool settings)

Comment: but the same cofig file works fine on my colegue pc and on mine it throw errors.

Comment: Then I would check IIS settings across the two machines

Comment: If the line number in error page is 0, you probably forgot an OOB module, https://blog.lextudio.com/jexus-manager-new-hope-to-end-oob-related-500-19-errors-193854de0d4d